# Background color not changing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, japplet

My job is to change the Background Color whenever the specific button is clicked to that of the Color mentioned on the button.But my JApplet doesnt seem to show any change in colors when the buttons are clicked.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorChange extends JApplet implements MouseListener{

    Color c = null;
    JButton b1;
    JButton b2;
    JButton b3;
    JFrame f;
    JPanel p;
    public void init()
    {   
        frame();
    }

    private void frame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel();
        b1= new JButton("RED");
        b1.addMouseListener(this);
        b2 = new JButton("BLUE");
        b2.addMouseListener(this);
        b3 =new JButton("GREEN");
        b3.addMouseListener(this);
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p.add(b3);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(arg0.getSource().equals(b1))
            c =  Color.red;
        else if(arg0.getSource().equals(b2))
            c = Color.blue;
        else if(arg0.getSource().equals(b3))
            c =Color.green;
        else
            c = Color.yellow;

        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void paint()
    {
        f.setBackground(c);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi this is a correction Generally JFrames are not used in applets. JPanels are for applets and JFrames are for Desktop applications.

Comment: `f = new JFrame();`  It would be more practical to launch this frame using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), especially since calling .. `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` .. will throw a security exception no matter *what* the security environment of the applet.  Of course, it would run 'just fine' in an IDE..

Answer (score 1):

For simply changing background color, it's not necessary to override `paint`, nor is it ever a good idea to do in a top level container in Swing. Since the `JPanel` `p` occupys the complete area of the content pane of the `JFrame`, you can use

```
p.setBackground(c);
```

Side notes:

- Use an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener` for handling `JButton` actions
- Use a `JDialog` rather than a `JFrame` for secondary windows in Swing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setBackground. 
I thing, it is

`f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);`

The frame color is not visible to the user, so you have to call the getContentPane method.